# Unable to start a jhipster-console on Windows

Tags: jhipster, yo

I'm not able to start **jhipster-console** on my docker instance in windows.

I followed the instructions for setting up Jhipster-Console [here](http://jhipster.github.io/monitoring/).

The three containers were deployed and running on my docker machine. When I check the status with a docker ps command, the output is :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
1b6ec3d8ac50        logstash:2.3.0-1            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/udp                           foobar_elk-logstash_1
41a605f92bae        jhipster/jhipster-console   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                           foobar_jhipster-console_1
f8465eb5e8e3        elasticsearch:2.3.1         "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   foobar_elk-elasticsearch_1
```

When I check the **elk-elasticsearch logs**, I get the following output :

```
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:09,458][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: your kernel is buggy and you should upgrade
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:09,938][INFO ][node                     ] [Radion the Atomic Man] version[2.3.1], pid[1], build[bd98092/2016-04-04T12:25:05Z]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:09,939][INFO ][node                     ] [Radion the Atomic Man] initializing ...
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:11,195][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Radion the Atomic Man] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:11,243][INFO ][env                      ] [Radion the Atomic Man] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda1)]], net usab
le_space [10.3gb], net total_space [17.8gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:11,247][INFO ][env                      ] [Radion the Atomic Man] heap size [1015.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:15,994][INFO ][node                     ] [Radion the Atomic Man] initialized
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:15,994][INFO ][node                     ] [Radion the Atomic Man] starting ...
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:16,298][INFO ][transport                ] [Radion the Atomic Man] publish_address {172.19.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:16,325][INFO ][discovery                ] [Radion the Atomic Man] elasticsearch/IQAEBHK3SW2tdRIySdkWUw
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:19,442][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Radion the Atomic Man] new_master {Radion the Atomic Man}{IQAEBHK3SW2tdRIySdkWUw}{172.19.0.2}{172.19.0.2:93
00}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:19,457][INFO ][http                     ] [Radion the Atomic Man] publish_address {172.19.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:19,457][INFO ][node                     ] [Radion the Atomic Man] started
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:45:19,524][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Radion the Atomic Man] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:46:02,214][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Radion the Atomic Man] [logstash-2016.05.27] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [logstash],
shards [5]/[1], mappings [_default_, syslog]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:46:02,644][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Radion the Atomic Man] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[log
stash-2016.05.27][4]] ...]).
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:46:02,707][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Radion the Atomic Man] [logstash-2016.05.27] update_mapping [syslog]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:46:02,874][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Radion the Atomic Man] [logstash-2016.05.27] update_mapping [syslog]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:46:02,894][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Radion the Atomic Man] [logstash-2016.05.27] update_mapping [syslog]
←[36melk-elasticsearch_1  |←[0m [2016-05-27 09:46:03,006][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Radion the Atomic Man] [logstash-2016.05.27] update_mapping [syslog]
```

But when I check the jhipster-console **logs**, I get the following output :

```
Attaching to foobar_jhipster-console_1
←[36mjhipster-console_1   |←[0m Waiting for Elasticsearch to startup
```

I'm certainly doing something wrong but I don't know what... Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `jhipster -registry` you have the `url` and activation of `logstash`

Example:

```
jhipster-registry:
    container_name: jhipster-registry
    image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v2.2.0
    volumes:
        - ./central-server-config:/central-config
    # By default the JHipster Registry runs with the "prod" and "native"
    # Spring profiles.
    # "native" profile means the filesystem is used to store data, see
    # http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html
    environment:
        - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native
        - SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
        - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_ENABLED=true
        - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_HOST=jhipster-logstash
        - JHIPSTER_METRICS_LOGS_ENABLED=true
        - JHIPSTER_METRICS_LOGS_REPORTFREQUENCY=60
```

This parametere are ok for you?